# Breakpoints not being hit when remote debugging Azure web app in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having an issue with my deployed web app that's not occurring locally, so I wanted to use remote debugging to see what's going on.

I'm following the steps outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure?view=vs-2017#remote_debug_azure_app_service

My site is already deployed, so I just right-clicked the app in Server Explorer and selected "Attach Debugger". My web app is launched, but none of my breakpoints are ever hit.

I have remote debugging enabled on my app:

[image]

Not sure if it matters, but I set my configuration to Debug locally, but maybe I need to somehow set it to Debug in Azure? (not sure how to do this)

[image]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? The steps in the Microsoft docs seem pretty straightforward.

Comment: is your remote app deployed with Debug build? Release configuration on publish won't work for debugging

Comment: @Simonare I don't believe so. How can I change that? If I change the configuration of my project to Debug and rebuild, there's no changes detected to check into source control

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy your application with Debug configuration rather than Release. For this open `Properties => PublishProfiles => yourProfile.pubxml` and find `<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>` and change it to     `<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>`

Comment: I don't have a PublishProfiles folder or pubxml file in my Properties folder, the only thing in there is a launchSettings.json. My site is deployed through checkins to my source control repository, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: I am not sure, I am not using build servers. but I am %90 sure that your application is deployed with release build configuration.

Comment: I think you're right, I just don't know how to switch it over to Debug instead of Release